# How to Pass Data from Dialog Fragment into Custom Adapters Particular Position

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am developing an android app for Restaurant Ordering system, Now I want to add some Description for the particular Item so that I had added the Dialogfragment and set it to the Custom Adapter ImageView Click listener, the dialog fragment showing correctly, as well as data, is also passing from edit text, but it shows in the last element of the listview. 
I had tried various procedures and method but it still getting the same please help me, guys.
 I am attaching the screen shots of my project
[New TABLE ACTIVITY WHERE IS LISTVIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naiCT.png)

[DIALOG FRAGMENT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uedC5.png)

[AFTER ADDING DIALOG FRAGMENT DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uP9ur.png)

Here I am Adding Custom Adapter Code

```
 public class CustomAdapter_MenuList extends BaseAdapter{

Activity activity;
Context CONTEXT;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
public List<GetandSet> details;
CustomAdapter_MenuList.ViewHolder viewHolder;
GetandSet getandSet;
TextView GrandTotal;
TextView txtTotalItems;
ArrayList<String>Desciption = new ArrayList<>();

private EditText mInput;
Button btnadd,btnclose;


String desc;

public CustomAdapter_MenuList(Activity activity,Context context, List<GetandSet> details,TextView txtGrandtotal,TextView txttotalitems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.CONTEXT = context;
    this.details = details;
    this.GrandTotal = txtGrandtotal;
    this.txtTotalItems = txttotalitems;
    this.layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return details.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return details.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{

    getandSet = new GetandSet();

    final float menu_rate = 
Float.parseFloat(details.get(position).getRate()); 


    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = 
 (LayoutInflater)CONTEXT.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newtable_template, null);
        viewHolder = new CustomAdapter_MenuList.ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (CustomAdapter_MenuList.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    for(int i = 0 ; i<details.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = i+1; j < details.size(); j++)
        {

if(details.get(j).getMenu_id().equals(details.get(i).getMenu_id()))
            {
                details.remove(j);
                j--;

                getandSet = details.get(i);
                getandSet.Menu_qty = details.get(i).getMenu_qty() + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    viewHolder.txtsrno.setText(details.get(position).getMenu_id());
    viewHolder.txtsrno.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    viewHolder.txtsrnotem.setText(String.valueOf(position+1));
    viewHolder.txtmname.setText(details.get(position).getM_name());
    viewHolder.txtrate.setText(details.get(position).getRate());

    getandSet = details.get(position);
    getandSet.Menu_price = menu_rate * getandSet.Menu_qty;
    viewHolder.txtqty.setText(getandSet.Menu_qty+"");
    viewHolder.txtprice.setText(getandSet.Menu_price +"");

    GrandTotal.setText(String.valueOf(grandTotal(details)));
    txtTotalItems.setText(String.valueOf(grandTotal(details,position)));

    notifyDataSetChanged();


    //Add Button Code

    viewHolder.btnadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getandSet = details.get(position);
            //updateQuantity(position, txtqty,itemrate, 1);
            getandSet.Menu_qty = getandSet.Menu_qty + 1;
            getandSet.Menu_price = menu_rate * getandSet.Menu_qty;
            viewHolder.txtqty.setText(""+getandSet.Menu_qty);
            viewHolder.txtprice.setText(getandSet.Menu_price +"");

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });


    //Minus Button 
    viewHolder.btnsub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getandSet = details.get(position);
            //updateQuantity(position, txtqty,itemrate, -1);
            if(getandSet.Menu_qty > 1)
            {
                getandSet.Menu_qty = getandSet.Menu_qty - 1;
                getandSet.Menu_price = menu_rate * getandSet.Menu_qty ;
                viewHolder.txtqty.setText(""+getandSet.Menu_qty);
                viewHolder.txtprice.setText(getandSet.Menu_price +"");

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });

    //Add Description Button 
    viewHolder.btn_Desc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openDialog(position);
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

//View Holder Class
private class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtsrno,txtmname, txtqty,txtrate,txtprice,txtsrnotem,txtdesc;
    Button btnadd,btnsub;
    ImageView btn_Desc;

    public ViewHolder(View view)
    {
        txtsrno = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_NTsrno);
        txtsrnotem = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_NT_srno);
        txtmname = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_NT_Item);
        txtqty = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_Nt_qty);
        txtrate = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_Nt_rate);
        txtprice = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_NT_price);
        txtdesc = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_NT_desc);
        btnadd = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
        btnsub = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_sub);
        btn_Desc = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_desc);
    }
}

//Grand - Total
private float grandTotal(List<GetandSet> items){
    float totalPrice = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < items.size(); i++) {
        totalPrice += items.get(i).getMenu_price();
    }
    return totalPrice;
}

//Number of Items
private int grandTotal(List<GetandSet> items,int p){
   int totalitems = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < items.size(); i++) {
        totalitems += 1;
    }
    return totalitems;
}

private void openDialog(final int position){
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
    View subView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogfragment_description, null);

    mInput = subView.findViewById(R.id.edt_desc);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    builder.setTitle("Add Description");
    builder.setView(subView);
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();

    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            desc = mInput.getText().toString();
            //getandSet = details.get(position);
            details.get(position).setDes(desc);
            viewHolder.txtdesc.setText(details.get(position).getDes().toString());
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    builder.show();
}
```

}

Comment: I think it will easy to help you if you add code of your adapter

Comment: hi Anton, as per your suggestion I had put my code into the adapter but the problem is still same.

Comment: Oh ;) Publish code here

Comment: I had the custom adapter's code with an dialog

Comment: I Done It, Just put the textview.settext after the opendialog()  method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        viewHolder.txtdesc.setText(details.get(position).getDes().toString());
        notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Just put this lines after completion of openDialog() method